# Month to date aggreate KPI query postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

I'm trying to find a way to obtain the amount of sales made from month to month but only comparing the aggregate total up to the current month's date.
In other words, I want to compare this month's sales up until now, against other months sales up until that month's same day.

**Example using today's date as a reference (2016-06-18):**

```
Total sales on January 2016 (*From 2016-01-01 to 2016-01-31*): 1000

Total sales on January 2016 (*From 2016-01-01 to 2016-01-17*): 650

Total sales on February 2016 (*From 2016-02-01 to 2016-01-17*): 670

Total sales on July 2016 (*From 2016-06-01 to current_date - 1*): 680
```

**The structure of my data is as follows:**

```
   date      sales
2016-01-01     5
2016-01-02     4
2016-01-03     5
2016-01-04     7
.
.
.
```

When I run the query I would like to have a monthly comparison of the totals mentioned above, so a result that looks like this:

```
 month     sales
2016-01     650
2016-02     670
.
.
2016-06     680
```

So comparing the month-to-date total of each month.

This is what I have tried so far and it seems to be fine, but somehow I always get a small difference whenever I make tests for limit days like the first of each month or the last.

```
select
order_month,
sum(sales) as sales
from table
where extract (day from order_date::date)
<=
extract (day from current_date::date) 
- case when extract (day from current_date::date)=1 then 0 else 1 end
    group by 1;
```

Comment: `count(distinct order_id)`?.. are not you calculating `sum(sales) over(partitioned by extract (day from order_date::date))` ?..

Comment: Yes sorry, edited the query